# SOAP with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, soap, callback

I have written following SOAP server code. It query database(mongoDB) return the result. But with callback methods it is returning null. Any suggestion how to return the values fetched from DB.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var http = require('http');
var wait=require('wait.for-es6');

//This has details of Mongoose schema to connect to mongoDB
var models = require('./models');

var getLocation = function(callback){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
        succesfull(pos);
        typeof callback === 'function' && callback(geoloc);
    }, function(){
        alert("fail");
    });
};

var service = {
    ws: {
        calc: {
            sumar : function(args) {
                var n = args.a + args.b;
                return { res : n };
            },

            multiplicar : function(args) {
                //console.log(args)
                var n = args.a * args.b;
                return { res : n }
            },
            GetAccessList : function(args){             
                //console.log(args);
                var AccessName = args.AccessPName;
                var AccessType = args.AccessPType;
                console.log("Access Point Name = " + AccessName);
                console.log("Access Point Type = " + AccessType);


                var data1 = null;
                //Get the details of the Access Point
                 models[AccessType].findByName(AccessName,{},function(err,data){
                    if(err) return callback(err);
                    data1 = data;                   

                    //Get details of the License plate for the selected access point
                    models["LprSensor"].readByLocationId(data._id,{},function(err,data){
                    if(err) return callback(err);
                    //console.log(data);
                    });         
                }));    

                console.log(data1);
                return { res : data1}
            }
        }
    }
}

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('wscalc1.wsdl', 'utf8'),

server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url)
});

server.listen(8000);
soap.listen(server, '/wscalc1', service, xml);
```

How to wait for callback and return the value back to client.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you are asking is how to make this code non-blocking so instead of using `return` to use `callback` instead.

see [node-soap, A SOAP client and server for node.js](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

```
// This is how to define an asynchronous function.
          MyAsyncFunction: function(args, callback) {
              // do some work
              callback({
                  name: args.name
              });
          }
```

compare to doing the same without callback:

```
MyFunction: function(args) {
              return {
                  name: args.name
              };
          }
```

Callback is used instead of return.